# Update "accepts marketing" for Shopify customer via API?

Tags: vue.js, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to update the accepts marketing for a user in shopify. Specifically I'm trying to allow them to sign up for a newsletter which will mark them as "accepts marketing".

This can be easily done using a liquid form and two attributes
type    email
name    contact[email]

However, this will refresh the entire page which I don't want.

I'm using a mix of Vue a liquid and figured I'd be able to submit this via an API in Vue
I tried just submitting to /contact since that's what the form does, but it will redirect to a captcha page and not work.

Then doing a bit more research I found [this](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/customer), but "accepts marketing" is deprecated.

Is there anyway of doing this without having the page refresh?

Comment: Use `email_marketing_consent` or `sms_marketing_consent`